# reducing oracle table entity

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

[image: first pic]

I want a query that make my table like this:

[image: second pic]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: You have to better explain the logic behind your needed result. Also, please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). And what have you tried so far?

Comment: What if you have a row where **two** columns are non-zero?

Comment: I dont have such rows

Comment: What makes you combine ID2 =  4 with ID1 = 2? Why not with ID1 = 3 or ID1 = 1? What is the locic you want applied here? (Also this looks very much like a bad database design. Maybe you want to correct this rather than writing complicated queries.)

Comment: Why is the `4` in the same row as the `2` but the `9` goes into the row where the `1` is located - what is the logic behind that?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain the logic you want to implement. Don't make us guess your rules by reverse engineering from your sample output

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select max(id1) as id1, max(id2) as id2, max(id3) as id3
from . . .
```

Comment: consider my table has a lot of rows I do not want max

Comment: @navidsedigh then you should have provided more details in your question. The query in this answer returns exactly what you defined as the intended output in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use `SUM()` here, because you might have negative numbers in a given column:

```
select sum(id1) as id1, sum(id2) as id2, sum(id3) as id3
from yourTable
```

If we use `MAX()`, then it would fail, if for example there were a `-2` in one of the columns.  In that case, the max would return zero.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that solution is optimal for executing, but:

```
select (select id1 from table where id1 <> 0) id1,
       (select id2 from table where id2 <> 0) id2,
       (select id3 from table where id3 <> 0) id3
from dual;
```

Comment: That will fail with an error ("sub-query returns more then one row")

Comment: Yeah with new topicstarter's conditions ofc it will fail. I have post this solution before...